# NSXML searching in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsxml, nsxmldocument

If I have this external XML file:

```
<drivers>
                <folder>
                    <name>Adobe</name>
                    <driver>
                        <name>acrobat distiller 3.0</name>
                        <filename>ADISTILL.PPD</filename>
                    </driver>
                    <driver>
                        <name>adobe laserjet ii cartridge</name>
                    <filename>ALJII523.PPD</filename>
                </driver>
                <driver>
                    <name>generic postscript printer</name>
                    <filename>defprtr2.ppd</filename>
                </driver>
            </folder>
</drivers>
```

Say I want to get the contents of "Adobe" and put them in an array, how would I do it?

I have the following, which gives me an array of "< name >" however, I don't know what the next step it.

```
NSString *item_name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@".//drivers/folder/name"];
NSArray *arr = [ads_xml nodesForXPath:item_name error:NULL];
```

ads_xml is an NSXMLDocument type.

Thanks!

P.S. Specifically I want the < name > and < filename > found under the < driver > node.. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself, which can be done in a number of different ways.
I can create array for all the names, using XPath and another array for the filename, and store the data in array variables that way.